# Extract Date range start field from dimension lookup to the next transformation in PDI

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a requirement to extract the "Date range start field" and "Table daterange end" from the previous step (Dim User) and load it into the next step (Bridge User Cohort). Here how my transformation looks.[image]

**Below is how my Dim User Lookup looks like**

[image]

**Bridge User Cohort**

[image]

version_effective_ts and vesion_expiry_ts should be loaded from the previous step.
Any suggestions how I can get this done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a workaround in this case. Since the "Dimensional Lookup Step"(Dim User) is actually updating/inserting a table *(i assume in your case its the User table)*, once your transformation has finished executing the Dim User step, use a Table Input Step, where you can query the same "User" table *(the one you have inserted into the dim user)* and based on the key id fields, use a "Stream Lookup" step to get the "date_from" and "date_to" *(in your case version_effective_ts and vesion_expiry_ts)*. And finally use the output step to update the version fields (as per your query).

Your transformation will look something like the image below. *You can consider "Source" in the image below as all the step before "Dim User".*

[image]

This will work out assuming that you have version_effective_ts and vesion_expiry_ts in your user table.

Having said, i am not sure about the performance and stuff. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks but we made a database change. As the user tables are quite big and adding lookups would hamper the performance. Also we had to keep the history. So we added version and key field in bridge_user_cohort and made changes to the transformation by replacing the insert/update step with a dimension lookup. Thanks anyways